# XSLT Preserve Paragraph Format

Tags: xslt

When my data is being exported from the database its in the correct format. When I put it into my XSLT style sheet it puts everything in a flat line. Is there a way to fix this? Thank you for your help.

Style Sheet

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="urn:user-scripts" xmlns:aras="http://www.aras.com">
      <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="yes" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="script msxsl:script"></xsl:output>
      <xsl:template match="Item[@type='Order']">
        <html>
          <body>
    <!-- Implementation Notes -->
            <table class="row">
              <tr>
                <td class="section" width="100%">
                  <b>Implementation Notes</b>
                </td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="fieldValue">
                  <xsl:value-of select="implementation_notes"></xsl:value-of>
                </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
            <table class="row" height="10">
              <tr>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
       </body>
      </html>
     </xsl:template>
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Data

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <Result>
          <Item type="Order">
            <implementation_notes>New Order.
    1. Instructions A
    1.1 Instructions A.1
    2. Instructions B
    2.1 Instructions B.1
    3. Instructions C
    3.1 Instructions C.1
    </implementation_notes>
         </Item>
        </Result>
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A simple way to do this**:

Replace:

```
              <xsl:value-of select="implementation_notes"></xsl:value-of>
```

with

```
              <pre><xsl:value-of select="implementation_notes"/></pre>
```

**Do note**:

This isn't an XSLT question at all. It is an *HTML* one. The observed browser behavior is due to the rule that a browser represents a group of whitespace characters as a single space.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you like to have the content of implementation_notes as rows in your table.

I think you should reconsider your DB output and have a xml tag around each line.
If this is not possible and you like to split the text with xslt 1.0 by "end of line" you have to split the text with recursive template calls.

Or if not relay table rows are needed put a hmtl  `<pre>..</pre>` around your content.

```
 <pre>
    <xsl:value-of select="implementation_notes"/>
 </pre>
```